# Translating predefined data Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the few tables with predefined data.
I translate whole application except this data from tables.
How can I do that with Apex?

I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Translation" within Apex won't translate data in your tables. If you want to have multilingual application (along with the data), you'll have to translate those values yourself and set which value belongs to which language.

Comment: Can you tell me more please? I can't find any useful document

Comment: There's nothing "more"; translate "dog" in English to "Hund" in German or "pas" in Croatian and store all those values in a table.

Comment: It means that I need to store values in these tables in different languages. If I have "New" in table I have to add another row "Neu". And then how to show that row when I switch on eg. German?

Comment: In a very simplified option, suppose that this table contains animals' names. Then you'd have `create table animals(language_id varchar2(3), value varchar2(20));` and store values like `'ENG', 'Dog'` or `'GER', 'Hund'` in there. When working with German language, you'd include `where language = :P1_LANGUAGE` into queries you use, where `P1_LANGUAGE` is a select list item which lets users pick the language they are working with.

Comment: Molim, i drugi put :)